# Weekday from date string in C++11

Tags: c++, date, c++11

I have date strings like this:

```
"2015-11-27"
```

and from them I want to determine the day of week.

This ([live sample](http://ideone.com/uRzzAd)) is how I would do it using `<ctime>`:

```
int dayOfWeek(std::string date){
    int y, m, d; char c;
    std::stringstream(date) >> y >> c >> m >> c >> d;
    std::tm t = {0,0,0,d,m-1,y-1900};
    std::mktime(&t);
    return t.tm_wday;
}
```

but I'm wondering whether there is a more canonical way to go about this in C++11?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Is that better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std:get_time()` to translate such a string to a `std::tm`.

The following program is a modified version of the program published at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_get.

The valid format specifiers for `std::get_time()` can be seen at 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "2015-11-27";
    std::tm t = {};
    std::istringstream ss(input);
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y-%m-%d");
    std::mktime(&t);
    std::cout << std::asctime(&t);
}
```

See it working at http://ideone.com/xAEjsr.

Comment: **Sun** Nov 27 00:00:00 2015? (same on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9014081bd440ec2))

Comment: @decltype_auto, `std::tm t = {};` wasn't the best idea. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: But - how to do it right? Locale imbue of stuff?

Comment: @decltype_auto. adding `std::mktime(&t);` seems to have fixed that problem.

Comment: Thanks; it's good to have that boilerplate without having to summon higher magic.